# Enable NSArrayController predicate based on checkbox

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-bindings, nsarraycontroller

I've got a static filter to turn on/off for an NSArrayController based on whether or not a checkbox is checked.  Right now I've bound the checkbox value to this:

```swift
private dynamic var filterPending: NSNumber! {
    willSet {
        willChangeValueForKey("filterPredicate")
    }
    didSet {
        didChangeValueForKey("filterPredicate")
    }
}
```

and then I bound the filter of the NSArrayController to this:

```swift
private dynamic var filterPredicate: NSPredicate? {
    guard let filter = filterPending?.boolValue where filter == true else { return nil }
    return NSPredicate(format: "pending > 0")
}
```

That seems to work properly, but feels like maybe I'm missing some easier way of doing this?

Comment: In ObjcC it would be `+ (NSSet *)keyPathsForValuesAffectingFilterPredicate { return [NSSet setWithObjects:@"filterPending",nil]; }`, no idea how that translates to swift.

Comment: I could do that too, instead of the filterPending.  I was thinking there might be an easier way though than having one 'thing' say that the predicate needs to change and another for the predicate.   Basically is there a cleaner way to do it without the two elements being done in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your set-up the value of `filterPredicate` *depends* on the value of `filterPending`. As *Gerd K* points out, the *Key-Value Observing* API allows you to specify this type of relationship by registering `filterPending` as a [dependent key](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002179-BAJEAIEE) of `filterPredicate`:

```
// MyFile.swift

class func keyPathsForValuesAffectingFilterPredicate() -> Set<NSObject> {
    return Set<NSObject>(arrayLiteral: "filterPending")
}

private dynamic var filterPending: NSNumber!

private dynamic var filterPredicate: NSPredicate? {
    guard let filter = filterPending?.boolValue where filter == true else { return nil }
    return NSPredicate(format: "pending > 0")
}
```

Comment: You don't need to return an object, you can just return Set<String>("filterPending")